# Pandas Time Series and groupby

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

[Edited to more clearly state root problem, which behaves differently if you use numpy 1.8 as dmvianna points out]

I have a DataFrame that has time stamps add other data. In the end I would like to not use a formatted time as the index because it messes with matplotlibs 3d plotting. I also want to preform a groupby to populate some flag fields. This is causing me to run into a number of weird errors. The first two work as I would expect. Once I bring `pd.to_datetime` into the picture it starts throwing errors.

runs as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.random.randint(100000, size=1000),
                    'type':np.random.randint(10, size=1000), 
                    'value':np.random.rand(1000)})

df['high'] = 0

def high_low(group):
    if group.value.mean() > .5:
        group.high = 1
    return group

grouped = df.groupby('type')
df = grouped.apply(high_low)
```

works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.random.randint(100000, size=1000),
                    'type':np.random.randint(10, size=1000), 
                    'value':np.random.rand(1000)})

df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')

df['high'] = 0

def high_low(group):
    if group.value.mean() > .5:
        group.high = 1
    return group

grouped = df.groupby('type')
df = grouped.apply(high_low)
```

throws error:
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1016), indices imply (3, 1000)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.random.randint(100000, size=1000),
                    'type':np.random.randint(10, size=1000), 
                    'value':np.random.rand(1000)})

df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
df = df.set_index('time')

df['high'] = 0

def high_low(group):
    if group.value.mean() > .5:
        group.high = 1
    return group

grouped = df.groupby('type')
df = grouped.apply(high_low)
```

throws error:
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1016), indices imply (3, 1000)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.random.randint(100000, size=1000),
                    'type':np.random.randint(10, size=1000), 
                    'value':np.random.rand(1000)})

df['epoch'] = df.time
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
df = df.set_index('time')
df = df.set_index('epoch')

df['high'] = 0

def high_low(group):
    if group.value.mean() > .5:
        group.high = 1
    return group

grouped = df.groupby('type')
df = grouped.apply(high_low)
```

Anyone know what I'm missing / doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to rewrite your question with sample data, expected output, and a clearer statement of exactly what the question is.

Comment: You say your groupby fails, what groupby??

Comment: after this I call: `data.groupby(['source', 'DoY'])`, which kicks the error I gave. I'll edit to make it clear.

Comment: @TristanMatthews I don't understand how dmvianna's answer solves that.

Comment: @AndyHayden its answered my question about how to add the data I wanted to my DataFrame without copying it and possibly messing up the order. I'm still not sure why the `groupby` / `apply` is failing when I do it one way and not the other, but it seemed easier to go after the more general question.

Comment: @TristanMatthews sorry, but I don't follow, dmvianna concedes that using to_datetime is equivalent (and you already had this).

Comment: @AndyHayden Your totally right, my problem went away when I upgraded to 1.8.0... so he answered my question in a different way and I didn't notice.

Comment: @TristanMatthews Ok, but that fact is totally not clear for anyone else who comes to this page in search of an answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42985/discussion-between-tristanmatthews-and-andy-hayden)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `pd.to_datetime`, I would use `np.datetime64`. It will work in columns and offers the same functionality as you expect from a datetime.index (np.datetime64 is a building block for datetime.index).

```
import numpy as np
data['time2'] = np.datetime64(data.time, 's')
```

Check the [Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

This would also lead to the same result:

```
import pandas as pd
data['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(data.time, unit='s')
```

Notice though that I'm using pandas 0.12.0 and Numpy 1.8.0. Numpy 1.7 has issues referred to in the comments below.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: How is this different from to_datetime followed by making it a column? (Actually this gives me `ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`... confusing)

Comment: @AndyHayden numpy has gone through major fixes between 1.6 and 1.8. At the moment, on my system (numpy 1.8.0 and pandas 0.12.0) `pd.to_datetime` ignores the unit and assumes every number I pass to it is a nanosecond, which was a numpy 1.7 bug. Numpy 1.8 gets it correctly.

Comment: yeah, I hadn't actually tried it. I'm getting the same error as dmvianna, numpy 1.7.1 and pandas 0.12.0, but your way seems much better if it works, so maybe I'll just update.

Comment: @dmvianna ah, that'll be why I get the error (a lot of people are still on 1.7.1 so this is definitely worth mentionining). Weird the OP didn't mention the exception (!) in to_datetime with unit='s'.

Comment: @dmvianna this doesn't explain how the result is different however (than using to_datetime). Once it's a column, aren't they the same?

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't know how pandas integrates with Numpy, but obviously if they were the same, `pd.to_datetime` and `np.datetime64` would lead to the exact same result in a given system, which they don't. I assume pandas subclasses Numpy, so most stuff would be the same, but API mismatches might occur (as in the case for the unit argument).

Comment: @dmvianna But I was claiming that they do, pd.to_datetime makes a datetime64 array (wrapped in a Series), and once you set it to a column then it also wraps in a Series.

Comment: @dmvianna pls put up the example where you think that the unit is ignored

Comment: @AndyHayden If you are stating that they *should* behave the same, and *after* you create the column, all behaviour would be the same, yes I agree.

Comment: @dmvianna you need ``unit='D'``, the 2nd argument is not the unit; works just fine for me

Comment: In [17]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,10,8)),unit='D')
Out[17]: 
0   1970-01-10 00:00:00
1   1970-01-09 00:00:00
2   1970-01-06 00:00:00
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00
4   1970-01-03 00:00:00
5   1970-01-06 00:00:00
6   1970-01-03 00:00:00
7   1970-01-04 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: @dmvianna FYI you can copy and paste *text*/code rather than an image.

Comment: @Jeff, copying text from an IPython notebook that includes both input and output, without editing, is rather ugly.

Comment: @dmvianna thanks for updating, I got it from your original answer, but that makes everything much clearer.

Comment: @dmvianna You can just highlite it with the mouse (select it), then paste like normal (its copied to the clipboard).